# How to repaint JComponent once after several repaint()?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

My program loops on a list of JButton. For each JButton, it repaints it each second:

```
public class a {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static Set<MyButton> components = new HashSet<MyButton>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel lPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,18));

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            MyButton lButton = new MyButton("Hello" + i);
            lPanel.add(lButton);
            components.add(lButton);
        }
        frame.add(lPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        blinking();
    }

    public static void blinking() {
        Timer blinkTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            boolean on = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (MyButton lButton : components) {
                    lButton.blink(on);
                }
                on = !on;
            }
        });
        blinkTimer.start();
    }
}

public class MyButton extends JButton {

    public MyButton(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public void blink(boolean on) {
        setBackground(on ? Color.DARK_GRAY : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        setForeground(on ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Result: 
[image]

I want to ensure that all the buttons update their background and foreground color in the same time.

`JButton extends JComponent`, and `JComponent.setBackground` calls `repaint()`, as well as `JComponent.setForeground`.

Therefore, each second my program calls `repaint()` two times for each button, and the colors are not always updated at the same time.

How can I ensure that the colors of all the buttons are updated at the same time? I think the solution is to call only one `repaint()`, maybe on the buttons container, but how can I do that?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @wisnix It'd be better if the OP posted an `[mre]` - which automatically expands to [mre].

Comment: I added a minimal example, but the problem is difficult to reproduce in a little program.

Comment: JButtons are double buffered, so you should not be seeing any button get redrawn twice.

Comment: *because the repaint() calls are well synchronized in little applications.* - they are also synchronize in a large application because all the reapint() method does is add all paint requests to the RepaintManager. The RepaintManager then consolidates the requests and repaints all the components at one time. If you can't produces an [mre] that demonstrates this is NOT happening, then we can't help because we can't possibly guess what you are really doing in your application.

Comment: Ok sorry, I edited the example and know the problem is reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: use `setIgnoreRepaint()` and repaint only the frame:

```
frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
for (JButton lButton : components) {
                    // blink the buttons background on and off
    lButton.blink(on);
}
frame.setIgnoreRepaint(false);
frame.repaint();
on = !on;
```

The setIgnoreRepaint doc is a bit misleading since it says to suspend repaint for system events. So we are thinking of events that the OS could send. But in fact it ignores the repaints (implicit or explicit), and does not ignore the method calls directly on the component (paint / paintImmediatly ... all that).

Comment: If you solved your question in this answer, then mark it as solved so others would know.

Comment: I have this message: You can accept your own answer in 2 days. I will accept it monday

Answer (score 1):

Are the buttons all in the same layer of the panel? Then why not use the background of that layer instead of the buttons' background?

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    private static JButton newButton() {
        final JButton b = new JButton("x");
        b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        //b.setOpaque(false); //Do not make this call, because setContentAreaFilled documentation says so.
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JButton tester = newButton();
        final Dimension testerDim = tester.getPreferredSize();
        final Dimension maxDim = new Dimension(1200, 700);

        final int rows = maxDim.width / testerDim.width,
                  cols = maxDim.height / testerDim.height;

        final JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, cols));
        final int n = rows * cols;
        buttonPanel.add(tester);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
            buttonPanel.add(newButton());

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        final Color bg = buttonPanel.getBackground();
        final Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            private boolean on = false;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                buttonPanel.setBackground(on? bg: bg.darker());
                on = !on;
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

I think this is the best you can do with a single core/thread.

Also, if you want other components between the buttons, where their background is not the same as the layer's one, then just make them opaque (`setOpaque(true)`), if they are not already.

Comment: The problem is that in my real application each button can have a different color. They must blink at the same time but the colors can differ

Comment: @Skartt Ah, oh.